# Galaxy Note is getting slower and less responsive

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, performance, samsung-galaxy-note, maintenance

I've had my Galaxy Note about 18 months. It's progressively getting slower and slower to respond to user input. Any tap has an unpredictable delay, up to a few seconds. Even typing has a noticeable lag to it. I frequently accidentally tap things twice because there's no response to the first tap.

Is there anything I can do? I'd happily completely wipe and start over at this point. It's at the stage where I barely use it for things like quickly looking up stuff on the net - it's just too tedious.

It's the stock Samsung Android 4.1.2. 350 MB free on the internal storage out of 2GB, 830MB free out of 11GB on the USB storage, and 1.7/14.7GB free on the memory card.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Such symptoms have often been attributed to the eMMC chip (which is in fact a small SSD that runs a [flash translation layer (FTL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system#Translation_layers) software). Android 4.3 added [TRIM](https://www.xda-developers.com/android/yet-another-reason-to-update-to-android-4-3-trim-support/) support to address this.

There exist solutions like [LagFix (fstrim)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grilledmonkey.lagfix) that run on rooted devices and essentially do the same. [Cyanogenmod's Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/EMMC_Bugs) has more information on buggy eMMC chips.

**However note:**
You may want to check your eMMC type first with [eMMC Brickbug Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.vinagre.android.emmc_check) first, to see if you have a known buggy type (where TRIM support is probably faulty).

Some background here, some Samsung eMMC chips are known to cause trouble (they're used in other brands too):
https://plus.google.com/101093310520661581786/posts/2eEd95oN1ZP

Comment: Ok, BrickBug reports "YES. Insane chip." So, is rooting the only way to fix this?

Comment: Also, LagFix (fstrim) is apparently incompatible with my device. Any alternatives? (Looks like there won't be an Android 4.3 for me...)

Comment: LagFix is incompatible because it does the same check as BrickBug and refuses to continue with yours. Brickbug's "YES. Insane chip." output means that your phone has a (faulty) eMMC chip with a buggy TRIM feature. You cannot use LagFix at all with it or very probably kill the eMMC chip. Safest would be to have it replaced by service. Is it still under warranty?

Comment: Here's LagFix' FAQ that includes the warning for faulty eMMC chips: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=1abb0476a305d582d6d036dd9be04428&p=37029420#post37029420

Comment: 1 year warranty. 18 months old. Poop.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the no. of you can take:-

1. Try restarting your device.
2. If restarting doesn't help, then install [app cache cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache) from play store
   and clear cache for all of your apps.
3. If above two doesn't work, try factory reset, it will not disappoint you.

Comment: Already done the first two. Are you sure about the third?

Comment: Fully sure, 100% in your sense

Comment: Factory reset creates an all nice and snappy device but once you reinstall the latest Facebook and all the apps you have learnt are indispensable you are back at the slow life. As with all gear new developments in software make use of the processing resources offered by later hardware and what was perfectly fine some years ago may now not be able to cope with all the activity of apps of today´s social media streams. For example going from a Galaxy Note 1 to a Note 3 makes all the difference in terms of snappiness on today´s software.